# Bazaar Explorer hangs when parent branch is unreachable

Tags: bazaar, remote-branch

I created a shared repository on my laptop. In that repository, I created a branch named `trunk`. Then I created an **unbound** branch of `trunk` on my desktop so I could do work on either machine and sync my changes manually.

This works pretty well except for one nagging issue. On my desktop, Bazaar Explorer is forever trying to reach the remote branch. Every time I hit Refresh (for example) Bazaar Explorer hangs for several seconds while it does ... something. If my laptop isn't on the network, Bazaar Explorer hangs for even longer and then displays the error message, "Not a branch: <branch URL>". Afterward, I can proceed as normal.

One of the reasons I switched to a DVCS from Subversion is that you can keep on working and commiting even when "the server is down". Technically, I *can* keep working, but the constant freezing is killing it for me. Is there a solution?

Comment: File a bug report please. https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr-explorer/+filebug

Answer (score 0):

Edit `.bzr/branch/branch.conf` and remove the line with `parent_location = ...`.

Note: later if you merge or pull from another branch, it will again save the `parent_location`. To prevent it from doing that, add the `--no-remember` flag when you merge or pull.

As [@bialix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65736/bialix) pointed out in a comment:

> if you want to disable remembering of `parent_location` you can also edit `branch.conf` and put there: `parent_location =` that is nothing (or space) after equal sign.

Comment: if you want to disable remembering of parent_location you can also edit branch.conf and put there: `parent_location = ` that is nothing (or space) after equal sign.